# create msi using wix

Tags: wix

I am developing a wix code to create a msi. i have added all the components and libraries to my wix project.But,i am not able to create a msi as i need.Please help me out.Here is my code,

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

<Product Name='SmartViewer'
          Id="*"
          Language='1033'
          Codepage='1252'
          Version='1.0.0'
          UpgradeCode='9C5E4073-EFDE-419B-935D-CE2632BC560E'>

    <Package Keywords='Installer,MSI'
             InstallerVersion='100'
             Languages='1031'
             Compressed='yes'
             SummaryCodepage='1252' />

    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="myapp.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="MyProgramDir" Name="myproject" >
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="proj1" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <Component Id='MainExecutable' Guid='*'>
            <File Id='ExecutableFile' Name='mv.exe' DiskId='1' Source='mv.exe' KeyPath='yes'/>
        </Component>
        <Directory Id="imageformats" Name="imageformats">
            <Component Id='jpeg4Library' Guid='*'>
                <File Id='jpeg4' Name='jpeg4.dll' DiskId='1' Source='jpeg4.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
            </Component>
        </Directory>

        <Component Id='Network4Library' Guid='*'>
            <File Id='Network4' Name='Network4.dll' DiskId='1' Source='Network4.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>

        <Component Id='Multimedia4Library' Guid='*'>
            <File Id='Multimedia4' Name='Multimedia4.dll' DiskId='1' Source='Multimedia4.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>

        <Component Id='QtGui4Library' Guid='*'>
            <File Id='Gui4' Name='Gui4.dll' DiskId='1' Source='Gui4.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>

        <Component Id='Designer4Library' Guid='*'>
            <File Id='Designer4' Name='Designer4.dll' DiskId='1' Source='Designer4.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>

        <Component Id='Core4Library' Guid='*'>
            <File Id='Core4' Name='Core4.dll' DiskId='1' Source='Core4.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>


        <Component Id='libmfxsw32Library' Guid='*'>
            <File Id='libmfxsw32' Name='libmfxsw32.dll' DiskId='1' Source='libmfxsw32.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>

        <Component Id='libiomp5mdLibrary' Guid='*'>
            <File Id='libiomp5md' Name='libiomp5md.dll' DiskId='1' Source='libiomp5md.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>

        <Component Id='ippcore7.1Library' Guid='*'>
            <File Id='ippcore7.1' Name='ippcore-7.1.dll' DiskId='1' Source='ippcore-7.1.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>

        <Component Id='ippccw77.1Library' Guid='*'>
            <File Id='ippccw77.1' Name='ippccw7-7.1.dll' DiskId='1' Source='ippccw7-7.1.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>

        <Component Id='ippccv87.1Library' Guid='*'>
            <File Id='ippccv87.1' Name='ippccv8-7.1.dll' DiskId='1' Source='ippccv8-7.1.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>

        <Component Id='ippccs87.1Library' Guid='*'>
            <File Id='ippccs87.1' Name='ippccs8-7.1.dll' DiskId='1' Source='ippccs8-7.1.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>

        <Component Id='ippccp87.1Library' Guid='*'>
            <File Id='ippccp87.1' Name='ippccp8-7.1.dll' DiskId='1' Source='ippccp8-7.1.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>

        <Component Id='ippccg97.1Library' Guid='*'>
            <File Id='ippccg97.1' Name='ippccg9-7.1.dll' DiskId='1' Source='ippccg9-7.1.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>

        <Component Id='ippcc7.1Library' Guid='*'>
            <File Id='ippcc7.1' Name='ippcc-7.1.dll' DiskId='1' Source='ippcc-7.1.dll' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>

        <Component Id='EULALibrary' Guid='*'>
            <File Id='EULA' Name='EULA.rtf' DiskId='1' Source='EULA.rtf' KeyPath='yes' />
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef> 


    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="MyProgramDir" Name="myproj" >
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="proj1" /
                    <Component Id="TextFileComponent" Guid="*">
                        <File Id="TextFile" Name="Logs.txt" DiskId="1"
                              Source="Logs.txt" KeyPath="yes" />
                    </Component>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Directory Id="DesktopFolder">
        <Component Id="ExecutableFileShortcutComponent" Guid="*">
            <Shortcut Id="ExecutableFileShortcut" Name="smart viewer" 
                  Description="Shortcut To Executable File"
                  Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]mv.exe" />
    </Directory>

    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
        <Directory Id="MyProgramDir" Name="myproj">
            <Component Id="ExecutableFileShortcutComponent" Guid="*">
                <Shortcut Id="ExecutableFileShortcut" Name="smart viewer"
                      Description="Shortcut To Executable File"
                      Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]mv.exe" />

        </Component>
     </Directory>

  </Product>
 </Wix>
```

The components are not getting the dll path.I tried passing the path to source in file id,still i find the same issue.Looking forward for a good suggestion.

Comment: What error are you getting? Also I see you are missing the feature tag which you would need to install your files..:)

Comment: The components are not getting added.It is not finding the source path in file id.

Comment: Is it still not finding them when specifiying the full path?

Comment: @jasonbourne How could you verify that components aren't added when you failed to create the MSI?

Comment: I get a error of file not found, which i feel is contrary to files are not been added. I have no idea about the way of coding in XML.Suggest me on this.

Comment: @Natalie Carr I tried with adding a path "$(var.INSTALLFOLDER)\Multimedia4.dll",still i get a same error saying file path not found!

Comment: The variable $(sys.CURRENTDIR) locates to the current directory..:)

<File Id="f1" Source="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)\bla"/>..just a tip if the files are stored in the current directory...have you defined `$(var.INSTALLFOLDER)`?

Comment: Thank you.How do i build it using msbuild?? I have no visual studio installed in my system!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the full path to the files:

```
<File Id="Microsoft.Practices.Unity"
      Name="jpeg4.dll"
      Source="$(var.BuildOutputDir)\jpeg4.dll" />
```

where `$(var.BuildOutputDir)` is the full path to a folder. If these files are in the output of another referenced project then you can use `$(var.OtherProject.TargetDir)`

Comment: If this is the correct answer please mark it so that others can easily see it, and I get the recognition! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your file does not contain valid XML. The following fragment is broken.

```
<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="MyProgramDir" Name="myproj" >
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="proj1" /
                <Component Id="TextFileComponent" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="TextFile" Name="Logs.txt" DiskId="1"
                          Source="Logs.txt" KeyPath="yes" />
                </Component>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

The line

```
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="proj1" /
```

should be

```
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="proj1" >
```

There is one `</Directory>` missing. You should also add `</Component>` at two positions. Try WiXEdit that points to invalid XML when it loads a .WXS file.

Additionally you should add a `<feature>`.

Comment: You typed all the code in the question? You're a hero! Please keep in mind there are more unbalanced XML nodes.